# How to set env with a dot?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, console

I tried doing that with export and set env, but it did not work. how to do it?

for example

```
~/directory$ export a.home=1 
bash: export: `a.home=1': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The dot is not a valid character in a shell identifier.
So the answer is "you cannot do what you ask":

> ```
>    name   A word consisting only of  alphanumeric  characters  and  under-
>           scores,  and beginning with an alphabetic character or an under-
>           score.  Also referred to as an identifier.
> ```

Comment: You can set var names with periods as per @Amos 's post below

Answer (score 25):

Actually a colleague just asked me and I found a work-around - use

```
env var.with.dots=value command
```

Comment: As accurate as the previous answer is, this one is much more useful.